# Controlled solenoid stroke length

Tags: servo, solenoid, speed, linear, actuator

Let me create a scenario to better illustrate the problem
I have 1500 pens that I want to individually actuate upwards with 3 different distances, ex: 10mm/15mm/20mm
I thought I could use a solenoid to do this, but I'm not sure if this is the best option and how accurate the solenoid will be, another point is that speed is very important to me, that's why I'm initially not considering servos for example.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you explain your project a little more? Controlling 1500 pens doesn't seem to be a trivial thing. What device (microcontroller, computer?) do you intend to use for this? How will those pens be placed? All of them have to be actuated at the same time? How much force does all of them have to make?

Comment: @mguima yes, absolutely... you are right, it isn't trivial
I'm planning to use a siemens micro controller to have the amount of ports I will need to manage each "pen" individually.

Below in the image is an example of how it will be placed - side by side

[1]: https://i.ibb.co/kc6GzHy/3G9FE7U.png

Not all need to be activated at the same time and the distance of the stroke can vary (10mm/15mm/20mm) from one to another, that's why each is individual...

the force is not much, each "pen" needs to have 5N

Comment: Having seen the illustration, my answer is not relevant. (And 5N is not a trivial force)

Comment: @BrianDrummond  Perhaps your servo solution is relevant for large force, if the servo drives a key-like cam that stops motion at 0cm, 1cm, or 1.5cm. The main force comes  from a master monster solenoid that can move 2cm. A very mechanical solution. You might even be able to do a 2-dimension MUX between cam-servos and multiple solenoids. But MUXing 1500 - Zowie!